# AWS code deploy deployment failed with github

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I have created a pipeline for code deployment with github, but it is failing at **DownloadBundle** with **Access Denied** error.

I have created a role with **AmazonEC2FullAccess** and **AWSCodeDeployRole** to the deployment iam and also crated role for ec2 **AmazonEC2FullAccess**
I have attached couple of screenshot for setting of code deployment group
also I have placed appspec.yml in the root directory of my repo.

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html/
    overwrite: true
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

[image]
[image]

Note: I am using Auto scaling

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose your EC2 instance has to access S3 as well, check if your EC2 instance has permission to access the related S3 Bucket. Also if you are using KMS for encryption of your bucket, your EC2 instance has to have KMS permissions as well.

Comment: ohh, yah I didn't given permission for S3. thanks for the help

Comment: My pleasure! @ChiragSModi

Comment: but now the error coming on AllowTraffic, the error code is showing ScriptFailed